# How to substitute “with” statement in mariadb 10.1

Tags: sql, mariadb-10.1

I use a third party software with MariaDB 10.1 How can I subsitute sql "with" statement (not available with MariaDB 10.1) ?

I would like to do something like that :

```
WITH mCte
AS (
  SELECT 
     @row_num: = @row_num + 1 AS Cpt
    ,field1
  FROM (
    SELECT @row_num: = 0 AS row_num
      ,myField AS field1
    FROM myTable
    ) AS T
  )
SELECT *
FROM mCte
WHERE Cpt BETWEEN 1 AND 5
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
select @row_num := @row_num + 1 AS Cpt, field1
from myTable t cross join
     (select @row_num := 0 as row_num) params
limit 5;
```

Normally, I would expect an `order by` in the query, but your code doesn't have one.

Comment: thanks, that's right there is an "order by" in my query. If I use 'limit' here and I would like to have "between 20 and 50" it doesn't work ?

Comment: @FredericCantenot . . . You can use `offset` with `limit`.  However, that is not the question that you asked.

Comment: thanks, yes that's right it was not my original question but I need to execute a between because I translate query from sql server to mariadb ! I'm going to take a look with limit ans offset, if you have an other way, please let me know. Thanks again for your help !